# How to use LINQ to query a subset of string

Tags: c#, string, linq

Suppose I have an unordered `List<String>` named `letters`:

```
letters.Add("d.pdf");
letters.Add("a.pdf");
letters.Add("c.pdf");
letters.Add("b.pdf");
letters.Add("e.pdf");
letters.Add("f.pdf");
```

I want to order that list alphabetically and then, take the elements between `b` and `d` (including the endpoints), so this will return a new list like `{"b.pdf","c.pdf","d.pdf"}`.

Comment: Should the comparisons be case sensitive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple `foreach` loop solution:

```
var letters = new List<string> {"d", "a", "c", "b", "e"};

            letters.Sort();

            var start = "b";
            var end = "d";
            var r = new List<string>();
            foreach (var l in letters)
            {
                if (l.CompareTo(start) >= 0 && l.CompareTo(end) <= 0)
                {
                    r.Add(l);
                }
            }
```

another simple solution:

```
var letters = new List<string> {"d", "a", "c", "b", "e"};
letters.Sort();
 var startIndex = letters.IndexOf(letters.Find(l=> l.CompareTo(start) == 0));
 var endIndex = letters.IndexOf(letters.Find(l => l.CompareTo(end) == 0));
 var r = letters.GetRange(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex + 1);
```

If you use `TakeWhile`, this solution should work, this is more Linq like. The main problem would be to have the starting element in the first index of collection, otherwise `TakeWhile` won't work.

```
    var letters = new List<string> { "d", "a", "c", "b", "e" };
    letters.Sort();

    var start = "b";
    var end = "d";
    var startIndex = letters.IndexOf(letters.Find(l=> l.CompareTo(start) == 0));
    var r = letters.GetRange(startIndex, letters.Count - startIndex)
              .TakeWhile(l => l.CompareTo(start) >= 0 && l.CompareTo(end) <= 0).ToList();
```

Comment: Your "LINQ" solution doesn't use any LINQ at all.

Answer (score 0):

This should work in your case:

```
letters.OrderBy(x => x).TakeWhile(x => x != "e.pdf");
```

If you want to generalize it you can write an extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> GetRange<TSource>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
        Func<TSource, bool> start,
        Func<TSource, bool> end)
{
     int counter = 0;
     foreach (var item in source)
     {
         if (start(item) || end(item))
         {
              yield return item;
              counter++;
              if(counter == 2) yield break;
         }else if (counter != 0) yield return item;
     }
}
```

Then use it:

```
letters.OrderBy(x => x).GetRange(x => x == "b.pdf", x => x == "d.pdf");
```

Or you can do that without using `LINQ`, `List<T>` has also a `GetRange` method:

```
letters.Sort();
int startIndex = letters.IndexOf("b.pdf");
int endIndex = letters.IndexOf("d.pdf");
var result = letters.GetRange(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex +1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is something built-in that would support this easily, but with the addition of a new extension method, you can do it really easily:

```
void Main()
{
    var letters = new List<string>();
    letters.Add("d.pdf");
    letters.Add("a.pdf");
    letters.Add("c.pdf");
    letters.Add("b.pdf");
    letters.Add("e.pdf");

    var results = letters
        .OrderBy(x => x)
        .SkipWhile(x => x != "b.pdf")
        .TakeTo(x => x == "d.pdf")
        .ToList();

}

static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TValue> TakeTo<TValue>(this IEnumerable<TValue> source, Func<TValue, bool> predicate)
    {
        bool predicateReached = false;
        foreach (var value in source)
        {
            yield return value;         
            predicateReached = predicate(value);
            if (predicateReached) yield break;
        }
    }
}
```

The `TakeTo` extension method works similar to the `TakeWhile` extension, except it will yield all values until and including the first value which matches the given predicate function.